# Synonym for "Social Program"

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a synonym for "Social Program" which would fit better into the following schedule:

> Annual Distributors Meeting Schedule:
>   1. Sales Workshop
>   2. Distribution and Logistics Meeting
>   3. Round Table Discussion
>   4. Social Program ???

Social Program just doesn't sound right to my ear.

Comment: What are you trying to convey?  "Social" as in "socializing" (like cocktail hour)?  That it's optional?  If you know what specifically it's going to be, why not just say that?

Comment: Can you give more details as to what you intend 'Social Program' to entail? Is it non-business entertainment? Is it an analysis of social implications of your business? Is your business providing social programs to the community? Is it open-bar and dancing?

Comment: Yes, as in dinner and something cultural. We don't know yet what the "Social Program" will be; we are having this meeting in the future but advertising it now, so it needs to be general. The social program will be finalized as the meeting approaches.

Answer (score 8):

Based on the question's comments, I would suggest something along the lines of

> 4  Dinner and entertainment (TBD)

An alternative, if you don't want to commit to advertising any kind of entertainment, or anything beyond event attendees socializing, is

> 4 Networking hour

Comment: +1 for *Dinner and entertainment (TBD)*. I'm not sure about *Networking hour*; maybe ditch the *hour* bit as it implies a time limit, but the other one sounds more inviting and will usually have networking opportunities anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest "***cocktails***," "***cocktail hour***," or "***mixer***."  All of these convey a social function.  The first two usually imply alcohol will be served.  The last does not necessarily, but is sometimes taken to mean that.

Answer (score 2):

Fellowship and conversation.  The first has a slightly religious feel so it might not suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Until you know what you're going to do, naming it is going to be a challenge.

- We have the room until 9 but the last thing ends at 8, so let's hang around for unstructured conversation? Networking
- There will be someone on stage directing us in doing something that will cause us to get to know each other and increase our bonding? Social Activity
- The bar will open and we expect the conversation to begin? Cocktails and Conversation
- There will be someone on stage entertaining and we will sit and watch? Entertainment

and so on. I think you'll find once you choose the activity, you'll be able to name it generically.

Answer (score 0):

I am using "Hangout" in a similar religious context.